# React timer component percentage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer

I am making a timer component in react which shows the percentage of the time left in circular progress bar. The timer is working fine but percentage is not working. I tried to search online to calculate time percentage but did not get a working example. The code for the timer is here

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class TimerCSS extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            hours: 2,
            min: 0,
            secs: 0,
            fin: false,
            percent: 100
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.myInterval = setInterval(() => {
            var {hours,min,secs,fin,percent} = this.state;

            if(secs > 0){
                secs--;
            } else {
                secs = 59;
                if(min > 0){
                    min--;
                } else {
                    min = 59;
                    hours--;
                    if(hours < 0){
                        fin = true;
                        hours = min = secs = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            this.setState(prevState => ({
                hours, min , secs , fin, percent: Math.round(prevState.percent - 0.83)
            }))
        }, 100);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){

    }


    render() {
        const {hours,min,secs,fin,percent} = this.state;
        console.log(percent);
        if(fin){
            return(
                <div>
                <center>Finished</center>
            </div>
            )
        } else {
        return (

              <div className={`c100 p${percent}`}>
                <span>1:59</span>
                <div className="slice">
                  <div className="bar"></div>
                  <div className="fill"></div>
                </div>
              </div>

        );
        }
    }
}

export default TimerCSS;
```

the circular progress is downloaded and its based on CSS only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a reference to your initial time (2 hours, if I understand well) in seconds (2 * 60 * 60), so:

```
this.state = {
  initialTime: 7200,
  hours: 2,
  min: 0,
  secs: 0,
  fin: false,
  percent: 100
}
```

then you need a reference to your currentTime in seconds, so inside your interval, before setState:

```
var currentTime = (hours * 60 * 60) + (min * 60) + secs;
```

finally you can get the percentage, so:

```
var percentage = currentTime / this.state.initialTime * 100;
```